# Tmux: pane title (#T) is reported as "fg" rather than something more informative

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, zsh, tmux

Is there a way to get Tmux to show a more informative pane name?

If in a particular pane I have suspended a process and come back to it (with Zsh that's invoking it with either `fg` or something like `%2`), that is what the pane's title becomes rather than its real title (which might be `vim ~/somepath/somefile`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some bit of *zsh* configuration that is doing this for you (probably a “preexec” command).

I have seen oh-my-zsh cause a [similar problem](https://superuser.com/a/320316/14827). If you are using it, then you might try putting `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE=true` in one of your configuration files. Otherwise, it will rename the window to be the first word of every command that you enter.